# How to Display offline map in iphone using Mapkit

Tags: iphone, ios, overlay, mkoverlay

How to Display offline map in iphone using mapkit?
if i use static image then how do i get current location and pin drop on it?
anyone has idea please suggest some solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this post [Force MapKit use cached map tiles only/disable network programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959245/force-mapkit-use-cached-map-tiles-only-disable-network-programmatically)

It tells about open source map OSM , helps offline map browsing.

Source from here http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-sdk.

Hope this helps , or r u looking for some thing else.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [What SDKs can be used for creating offline maps application for iPad/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940545/what-sdks-can-be-used-for-creating-offline-maps-application-for-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS4+, you can use an image MKOverlay to overlay whatever you want on top of a MapKit map.  You can provide a semi-transperant base map of your own providing to display when the underlying Google Map can not be loaded.  But you can not control what MapKit is doing under the hood caching Google maps.