# What SDKs can be used for creating offline maps application for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ipad, maps, cloudmade

we are developing an offline city map application for iPad, using Cloudmade SDKs. I'm curious, is there are any other SDKs which could be used for offline applications ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better solution for me is:

1.- Generate your own maps with [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/#/tilemill) from Mapbox and then export to MBTiles format.

2.- Get the [mapbox-ios-example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example) and use the MBTiles file you just generated.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Meta. I think every newbie should be redirected there after registering! It's so many concepts to learn... I think stackoverflow will change definitely the way developers work!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with April, 2014 there is also [skobbler's /Telenav's SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com) - it's got full offline capabilities (map rendering, routing & rerouting) and a map cutting tool if you want a map of a custom area (e.g. you provide the gpx enclosed polygon and you get back a map of that area)

See some examples in the [demo apps](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) and the [how-to's](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios)