# Does MKMapView supports offline maps, or offline maps downloads?

Tags: ios, mapkit

Since there is a demand for map use in China and since China cannot use Google Map Services, I am wondering if MKMapKit supports offline maps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Display offline map in iphone using Mapkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323882/how-to-display-offline-map-in-iphone-using-mapkit)

Answer (score 1):

MapKit does not allow you to do this. If you want this functionality, you should probably use a different mapping framework, like OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 0):

Not Support offline right now. better to try other map frameworks like 
1.Bing Maps( Microsoft Bing suite)
2.WikiMapia Map etc