# Cloudmade Status

Tags: ios, geolocation, maps, cloudmade

I've been looking at using Cloudmade, but it feels rather unloved. There has been a single blog entry since June, the forums are suspiciously quiet and its iOS examples page carries information about preparing for iOS4. Is Cloudmade a dying/abandoned project or is it something worth looking at?

Comment: I am running in the same doubt, i have emailed the support service to ask if they are willing to update their example(and so their API) to be compatible with the iOS5 and their respond that they are currently focused on other type of projects, here is their message: `For now - no, we are now focused on other products and do not have time to port SDK.

Sorry, that can't help you here.
With best regards,`. I think you may perhaps be happy to adapt some projects in githup that help you to draw polylines in iOS app, here is an example: https://github.com/Surya121/SBMapWithRoute

Comment: Yep. I got a nice email back from them too, but it didn't fill me with confidence. Didn't use it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Couple weeks ago we've launched new website http://cloudmade.com/ We no longer provide old iOS SDK, but we working on new one.