# iOS - Empty map tiles / Switch map to offline mode when on 3G/cellular

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit, offline, offline-mode

I need my application to switch to offline mode even if `3G` is enabled.

I am using **AFNetworking** and it's quite easy to suppress all the `HTTP` operations, but how do I handle the screens which have maps?

I don't want to do any data transfer, so I either need to cut off the internet access to the `MapView` or `replace` the tile request with empty offline tiles.

Is there any way to achieve this with **MapKit** and without using any external map library?

PS: I found a related-question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959245/force-mapkit-use-cached-map-tiles-only-disable-network-programmatically), but there was no clear answer and the topic is quite old (for example, **CloudMade** does not have API for **iOS 6** yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you are not looking for an external library, but check out the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which can do this. MapKit has unpredictable caching and offline behavior and there are no APIs exposed with which to manage those features.

Comment: Finally, I just created an empty map source for MapBox and I replace MKMapView with a RMMapView from MapBox and I achieved what I needed. The only problem was rewriting what annotations or routes to put on map, but that was not a big task.